# PayPal pre-approval giving error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used PayPal api in which first i do preapproval and then make chained payment using that approval key. Everything works fine on my local server. But as on live its giving me below error.

Preapproval

Error

```
PreapprovalResponse Object
(
[responseEnvelope] => ResponseEnvelope Object
    (
        [timestamp] => 2015-05-01T08:38:40.374-07:00
        [ack] => Failure
        [correlationId] => 88fffca2a737c
        [build] => 15743565
    )

[preapprovalKey] => 
[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => ErrorData Object
            (
                [errorId] => 580001
                [domain] => PLATFORM
                [subdomain] => Application
                [severity] => Error
                [category] => Application
                [message] => Invalid request: Data validation warning(line -1, col 0): null
                [exceptionId] => 
                [parameter] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ErrorParameter Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [value] => Data validation warning(line -1, col 0): null
                            )

                        [1] => ErrorParameter Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [value] => Data validation warning(line -1, col 0): null
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

> My request is

requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fredesignbox.com%2Fopendemo%2Fhappyfund%2Fcheckout&currencyCode=RUB&maxAmountPerPayment=1%2C032.00&maxNumberOfPayments=1&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1%2C032.00&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fredesignbox.com%2Fopendemo%2Fhappyfund%2Fcheckout_action%2Faction%2FafterApproval&startingDate=2015-05-01&feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER

> Response is

responseEnvelope.timestamp=2015-05-01T08%3A38%3A40.374-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=88fffca2a737c&responseEnvelope.build=15743565&error(0).errorId=580001&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request%3A+Data+validation+warning%28line+-1%2C+col+0%29%3A+null&error(0).parameter(0)=Data+validation+warning%28line+-1%2C+col+0%29%3A+null&error(0).parameter(1)=Data+validation+warning%28line+-1%2C+col+0%29%3A+null

What's wrong i cannot understand.

**EDIT**

> On local my ssl version is 
>       **OpenSSL/0.9.8y** and 
>    on live its  **NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC**

Answer (score 1):

```
$maxpaymentss = floor(2000/68.50);

$data = array(

    'ClientDetails' => array(
        'applicationId' => 'My_APP',
    ),
    'returnUrl' => 'http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html',
    'cancelUrl' => 'http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html',
    'startingDate' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
    'endingDate' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
    'maxAmountPerPayment' => 68.50,
    'maxNumberOfPayments' => $maxpaymentss,
    'maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments' => 2000.00,
    'maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod' => 1,
    'currencyCode' => 'USD',
    'requestEnvelope' => array(
        'errorLanguage' => 'en_US',
        'detailLevel' => 'ReturnAll'
    )
);
```

these are the required fields for the live mode of PayPal adaptive preapproval.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "," in the "maxAmountPerPayment" and "maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments" field and try again . It should work fine